# How to strsplit using '|' character, it behaves unexpectedly?

Tags: r, regex, string, special-characters

I would like to split a string of character at pattern "|"

but

```
unlist(strsplit("I am | very smart", " | "))

[1] "I"     "am"    "|"     "very"  "smart"
```

or

```
gsub(pattern="|", replacement="*", x="I am | very smart")    

[1] "*I* *a*m* *|* *v*e*r*y* *s*m*a*r*t*"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that by default `strsplit` interprets `" | "` as a regular expression, in which `|` has special meaning (as "or").

Use `fixed` argument:

```
unlist(strsplit("I am | very smart", " | ", fixed=TRUE))
# [1] "I am"       "very smart"
```

Side effect is faster computation.

[`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stringr) alternative:

```
unlist(stringr::str_split("I am | very smart", fixed(" | ")))
```

Answer (score 18):

`|` is a metacharacter. You need to escape it (using `\\` before it).

```
> unlist(strsplit("I am | very smart", " \\| "))
[1] "I am"       "very smart"
> sub(pattern="\\|", replacement="*", x="I am | very smart")
[1] "I am * very smart"
```

Edit: The reason you need two backslashes is that the single backslash prefix is reserved for special symbols such as `\n` (newline) and `\t` (tab). For more information look in the help page `?regex`. The other metacharacters are `. \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?`

Comment: Thanks!!! But how did you know we needed 2 backslashes there?? I tried with one only.

Answer (score 5):

If you are parsing a **table** than calling `read.table` might be a better option. Tiny example:

```
> txt <- textConnection("I am | very smart")
> read.table(txt, sep='|')
     V1          V2
1 I am   very smart
```

So I would suggest to fetch the wiki page with [Rcurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html), grab the interesting part of the page with [XML](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) (which has a really [neat function](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=XML%3areadHTMLTable) to parse HTML tables also) and if HTML format is not available call `read.table` with specified `sep`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Pipe '|' is a metacharacter, used as an 'OR' operator in regular expression.

try 
`unlist(strsplit("I am | very smart", "\s+\|\s+"))`

Comment: again, I have to put 2 backslashes to make it work: unlist(strsplit("I am | very smart", "\\s+\\|\\s+"))