# strsplit with vertical bar (pipe)

Tags: string, r, split, strsplit

Here,

```
> r<-c("AAandBB", "BBandCC")
> strsplit(as.character(r),'and')
[[1]]
[1] "AA" "BB"

[[2]]
[1] "BB" "CC"
```

Working well, but

```
> r<-c("AA|andBB", "BB|andCC")
> strsplit(as.character(r),'|and')
[[1]]
[1] "A" "A" "|" ""  "B" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "B" "|" ""  "C" "C"
```

Here, the answer is not correct. How to get "AA" and "BB", when I use '|and'? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to use as.character() in strsplit function. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [character "|" in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382425/character-in-r)

Comment: found this question because i tried splitting on `"\|"`, leading to the error, `'\|' is an unrecognized escape...`.  I just needed to add a second backslash `"\\|"` as indicated by @RockScience.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you can read on ?strsplit, the argument split in function strsplit is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Hence either you need to escape the vertical bar (it is a special character)

```
strsplit(r,split='\\|and')
```

or you can choose fixed=TRUE to indicate that split is not a regular expression

```
strsplit(r,split='|and',fixed=TRUE)
```