# R splitting string based on double-character delimiter

Tags: r

I have a string `"Test||Test1||test2"` that I want to tokenize by `||`. However, what I got is always the individual characters (with 2 empty chars at both ends):

`""   "T"  "e"  "s"  "t"  "1"  "|"  "|"  "T"  "e"   "s"   "t"   "2"   "|"   "|"   "T"   "e"   "s"   "t"   "3"   ""`

I have tried both: `strsplit(myString, "||")` and `str_split(myString, "||")` from the library `tidyverse` (from this [tutorial](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html), seems like it should work) but got the same incorrect result.

How do I tokenize string based on double/multiple-character delimiter?

Comment: Duplicate of [strsplit with vertical bar (pipe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193219/strsplit-with-vertical-bar-pipe) and [How to strsplit using '|' character, it behaves unexpectedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382425/how-to-strsplit-using-character-it-behaves-unexpectedly)

Comment: @M-- Ok I agree, I did not know the pipe char `|` was a special character in R. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `fixed` as `|` is a metacharacter for `OR`

```
library(stringr)
str_split(myString, fixed("||"))[[1]]
#[1] "Test"  "Test1" "test2"
```

Or another option is to escape (`\\` - as @joran mentioned in the comments) or place it inside a square bracket

#### data

```
myString <- "Test||Test1||test2"
```