# Library (stringr) doesn't work for "|"

Tags: r

I use stringer package to replace some of the characters. It is perfectly fine for all the characters but surprisingly doesn't work for |. I wish to remove |. But it doesn't work.

```
library(stringr)

 dts$new <- str_replace_all(dts$Campaign, "|", "")
```

my data set is

```
#dts  
id  Campaign 
1   C|D|E
```

and I wish the following output:

```
id  Campaign 
1   CDE
```

Comment: `|` means "or" in regex - try `\\|` or `[|]`

Comment: Thank you so much @thelatemail. It worked

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382425/character-in-r

Comment: Awesome! Should I delete the question since it is somehow duplicated?

Comment: Nah... it's all good - I'll just mark it as a duplicate and it can stay. It's probably more specific than the previous question and has a better title.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am happy to accept your answer if you write it down as an answer.

Comment: You can just accept old mate's answer below - I don't need the points :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 str_replace_all(dts$Campaign, "[|]", "")
```